# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Failed to transform class with name UnitySaveFCPort$PortMetric.Reason:[source error]a constructor cannot be static

Tags: java, enums, powermock, powermockito

I am new to powermock. I am trying to mock a private method and run the testcase.
But I am getting following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name UnitySaveFCPortPerfByInterval$PortMetric. Reason: [source error] a constructor cannot be static

    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:283)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1.run(CachedClass.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:251)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.populateMethods(MetaClassImpl.java:390)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.fillMethodIndex(MetaClassImpl.java:340)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3224)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:222)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:859)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at TestUnitySaveFCPortPerfByInterval.testFCPortPerfByInterval(TestUnitySaveFCPortPerfByInterval.groovy:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] a constructor cannot be static
    at javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(MethodCall.java:241)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:370)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:220)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1437)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.ClassMockTransformer.transformMockClass(ClassMockTransformer.java:65)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.transform(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:247)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:264)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: compile error: a constructor cannot be static
    at javassist.compiler.MemberCodeGen.atCallExpr(MemberCodeGen.java:474)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstCodeGen.atCallExpr(JvstCodeGen.java:244)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:338)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:398)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(MethodCall.java:235)
    ... 60 more
```

I have been mocking private methods for other classes, everything works fine.
The only difference between other classes and the class for which test case is failing is it has enum called :

```
private enum PortMetric {
        READ_IOS, WRITE_IOS, KBYTES_READ, KBYTES_WRITTEN
    }
```

Comment: Please add a small self contained code sample that demonstrates how to reproduce this - with only the enum and stack text it’s hard to help.

Comment: Sample code to reproduce the issue :  class SampleCode {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(method2())
    }

    private PortMetricEnum method2() {
        return PortMetricEnum.READ_IOS
    }

    enum PortMetricEnum {
        READ_IOS
    }
}

Comment: Sample testcase :  import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SampleCode.class)
class TestSampleCode {

    @Test
    void testMethod1() {
        SampleCode obj = PowerMockito.spy(new SampleCode())
        PowerMockito.doReturn("North").when(obj, "method2")
        System.out.println(obj.method1())
    }


}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because my enum was within a class and according to java specification enum within a class is by default static. Once I put the enum outside class, issue was resolved.